# WCF Service failing - HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#

I was getting exception while making a call the my WCF service more larger request XML object content length 65708, where it is working without any issues with request XML file content length less than this.

This is service we are exposed to external clients and I used SoapUI to debug the service and I am getting the exception HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n] and not even hitting to the debug point. I searched the web and applied the configuration values provided, but none of them helped me to resolve the issue.

After all the config changes, my web.config file is looks like this (only binding part).

```
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="GDASHttp" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

I didn't changed any settings in the client file as I can getting the exception from SoapUI and issue is related to server configuration only. I do understand the issue with some the settings is accepting according to the file size, but not sure what is maximum values we can provide in the above settings.

I modified the IIS settings as per some of the Google advises in  the server and this is my changed applicationhost.config file.

```
<location path="Default Web Site/GDAS.FY15R2.3.1/Trusted" overrideMode="Allow">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute" />
            <security>
                <ipSecurity>
                    <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" subnetMask="255.255.255.255" allowed="true" />
                </ipSecurity>
                        <requestFiltering> 
                        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="40000000" /> 
                        </requestFiltering> 
            </security>
            <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="2147483647" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that an HTTP status code in the 400s (i.e. 400 Bad Request) points to an issue originating on the client side, not the server side. Server issues typically produce status codes in the 500s.

Answer (score 0):

This is the value you would use:  2147483647

But for WCF you need to configure that in both the client and the server.  You can not just change the Server Binding, as the two Bindings are basically shaking hands so the MAX value should match in both configs.

I would turn on tracing and see exactly what is happening.

Comment: I am not a SoapUI expert, but when sending messages from SoapUI there is probably a configurable length.  If your outgoing message is too large I would think you would get that error.  You can also use Fiddler for the request itself, and see the actual size of the request.  You might actually be larger than the limit you are configuring.  If that is the case you need to break up your resultset in multiple messages.

Comment: Also with a 400 error you are not even hitting your server endpoint configured correctly.  WCFStorm can help in diagnosing WCF errors.  I would reexamine your entire Server config, and then use the tool to generate a new client based off of that and then hit it with SoapUI, or WCF storm.